# p:ajax event for pagination of lazy p:dataTable

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, datatable, pagination

I'm having trouble finding an ajax event that will execute my javascript when my list is updated during lazy loading of my datatable. This javascript is responsible for updating an image coverflow based upon my list that gets repopulated during initial datatable loading, when doing pagination, and changing the number of records on a page. Any help with finding a way to make an event execute my javascript during these situations is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Primefaces 3.3.1
Mojarra 2.1.5
JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its not specific for Lazy Loading :

In order to run a js function upon pagination complete use the `p:ajax event="page"` (It might also work for *changing the number of records on a page*)

Like this

```
<p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="myJsFunction();"></p:ajax>
```

Additional event types are

> page - On pagination.
>
> sort - When a column is sorted.
>
> filter - On filtering.
>
> rowSelect - When a row is being selected.
>
> rowUnselect - When a row is being unselected.
>
> rowEdit - When a row is edited.
>
> rowEditCancel - When row edit is cancelled.
>
> colResize - When a column is being selected.
>
> toggleSelect - When header checkbox is toggled.
>
> colReorder - When columns are reordered.
>
> rowSelectRadio - Row selection with radio.
>
> rowSelectCheckbox - Row selection with checkbox.
>
> rowUnselectCheckbox - Row unselection with checkbox.
>
> rowDblselect - Row selection with double click.
>
> rowToggle - Row expand or collapse.
>
> contextMenu - ContextMenu display.

(Taken from [primefaces user guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation))

Comment: Thanks for the information! I added the "page" event to execute my javascript, but this breaks my pagination for some reason. It doesn't return an error, but pagination is no longer functional. I'm not sure what the issue may be. Any other suggestions?

Comment: seems that it something in your js function than... had no issues with the approach I suggested...

Comment: Thanks again for your info and suggestion. I created a generic js function and that worked every time during pagination. So, I agree that this issue is due to my js function. This function does work perfectly when executed during a commandButton click. So, I may have to find an alternative solution to my issue at this point. Thanks!

Comment: I would like to update a backing bean when the loading is done. onComplete can be used for calling JS code, how can i update a backing bean?

Comment: @vinay, better ask a new detailed question

Comment: @Daniel I thought so and I asked the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532864/on-primefaces-datatable-lazy-loading-complete-update-backing-bean/26533004#26533004

Answer (score 2):

In primefaces 6.2, here is the full list of dataTable events.

> page
>   sort
>   filter
>   rowSelect
>   rowUnselect
>   rowEdit
>   rowEditInit
>   rowEditCancel
>   colResize
>   toggleSelect
>   colReorder
>   contextMenu
>   rowSelectRadio
>   rowSelectCheckbox
>   rowUnselectCheckbox
>   rowDblselect
>   rowToggle
>   cellEditInit
>   cellEdit
>   rowReorder
>   swipeleft
>   swiperight
>   tap
>   taphold
>   cellEditCancel

from the docs: [javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorHolder.getEventNames()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html)