# External Primefaces datatable values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Our application makes use of a fairly large paginated lazy-loaded . In a separate element on the page, I have a <span> with '22800 projects' as a count of total rows, which is subject to change depending on some external form fields on the page and some other things. Unfortunately, that <span> is above the markup for the datatable (before the lazyModel load method runs the query to get the rows+count). What I would like to do is be able to update that <span>'s text with the row count on page load and every other update the datatable makes. Is this possible?

Comment: do you "have" to use a span? you cant use a JSF component? like `h:outputLabel`?

Comment: Why don't you put it below in the xhtml and use some simple dom manipulation or css to move it 'up'

Comment: My span tag does have an outputText inside of it with an ID. Is there something that can auto-update that? If I could find a way to trigger JS on updates, I could hack-fix it, but would be surprised if there isn't a way that Primefaces offers to update it.

Comment: After some more searching. It looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867321/pajax-event-for-pagination-of-lazy-pdatatable may solve my issue. Thanks for the replies, though.