# Call javascript function on Primefaces dataTable paginator

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, datatable

I have a Datatable with a paginator inside of the header. I also have a Checkbox `TestBox` that just gives me a boolean that determines if something on this datatable page is shown or not. 
now when I change the dataTable Page I want that this `TestBox` gets unchecked
This are the tries I did.
First one is direct inside the XHTML page:

```
$(document).ready(function {
         $(".ui-paginator").click(function () {
                $("#TestBox").checked = false;
            });
        });
```

The second one I tried is inside my functions.js file:

```
$(".ui-paginator").click(){
document.getElementById("TestBox").checked = false;};
```

This is all I came up with but I think the problem is that I cant adress the pagination in this way but I did not find any other way to do it.

Comment: There is a page event that can be used with a `p:ajax` or `pe:javascript`....

Comment: @Kukeltje do you have a link for me that explains this more detailed?

Comment: @Kukeltje I found a Link to this myself now. But Thank you for giving me this Hint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867321/pajax-event-for-pagination-of-lazy-pdatatable/13867564

Comment: if you just need it client-side, use `pe:javascript` (and the PrimeFaces documentation and showcase help a lot to)

Comment: @Kukeltje The Problem now is that this does not work with The dataTable pagination which i am using